# Sudden image burn-in on laptop screen - maybe caused by malfunction of graphics card?

Tags: nvidia-graphics-card, lenovo-laptop, burn-in

I have experienced two images burnt-in my laptop screen very suddenly. The images did **not** burn-in over a long period of time, as it would happen with an old tube monitor. Instead, a **single frame** seems to be burnt in.

At the first time it occured, the windows desktop was shown. In the burnt-in image one could clearly read the minutes of the clock in the taskbar. I assume that it happened exactly after I had opened the lid and the image moved from an external monitor to the laptop screen. This was just after I had switched in the BIOS from a "Hybrid" graphcis mode to the "Discrete" mode (details about my system below). Even though I was not sure if that related, I immediately switched it back to "Hybrid". After a couple of days the burnt-in image faded mostly away.

One and a half years later I decided to give the "Discrete" mode another chance when I was about to reinstall the system. And again, just after I booted from USB, the next image got burnt in (this time, the UI of the bootable recovery tool is clearly visible). The interesting part is now that this time the lid of the laptop **was closed all the time**. I just finished the recovery process using my external monitor, checked if the system was OK, shut it down and left it powered off on the desk over night. Only on the next day I saw the burnt-in image. That's really spooky, because now there is an image burnt into the screen that was never shown on that screen.

My explanation goes in the direction that for some reason the discrete graphic card still tries to drive the display, even though it is turned off, but only when the system is running in the "Discrete" mode. The image is then not really burnt into the LCD pixels or something, but rather stay in some kind of memory.

Could that be? Are there any other crude theories? Maybe even a good explanation? Or even a fix?

```
Technical details:
Lenovo P50 from late 2016
 - Nvidia Quadro 2000M
 - 4K Display
 - Intel Xeon CPU E3-1505M v5

External monitor connected 1st time via display port, 2nd time via dock on USB-C port
```

**Update 1:**

Additional information: the areas of the screen where a "burnt-in" image is visible, are flickering (about 30 Hz?). I took a short video clip one and a half days after it appeared, so it already faded away a lot. But you can still see some text shining through. It is barely visible when the actual screen content is full white and less visible when it is full black. It can be best seen on a grayish background like my taskbar in the video. The camera finally managed to focus after 6 seconds: https://youtu.be/mxaZcyhBHvI

[This is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/16TCB.png), but it is hard to judge on a still image. Better have a look at the video.

Comment: We can only judge this if you can post an image of the screen, and if you open an image in full screen that has the full color of white and 3 more images with the colors red, green, blue, it can be detemined if this is indeed burnin or something else.

Comment: Based on the description, it sounds more like an issue with the graphics card than the monitor. Have you looked for new driver versions? This looks like the most recent: https://www.nvidia.com/Download/driverResults.aspx/130177/en-us

Comment: I have updated the question with some more details how it looks and also added a video I took yesterday. Now it faded even further away and is barely visible on a photo/video. So unfortunately I cannot send better data to analyze it (@LPChip). I will not try to trigger the issue again because I fear that it might get worse... it never disappeared completely; in a dark room it's a bit annoying even after month.

Comment: Seeing the video evidence and the image, this is definitely a hardware problem of some sorts. Could be a faulty monitor connection or even a problem with the screen itself. Not sure if this is fixable and if so, if it will cost less than replacing the laptop entirely.

Comment: No doubt that this issue is hardware related. But because it can be triggered by a Bios setting ("Discrete Graphics Mode") I don't believe that it is something like a "loose connector" or a "broken LCD". Btw: with an external monitor everything is perfect. Maybe I'm asking at the wrong place. Is there another place like SuperUser but with more hardware experience?